# Matching, sorting and returning multiple nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have multiple nodes in Neo4j, they have labels like Person, skill, interests, company etc (about 8-9 different labels). I want to search/match the properties in these nodes and return a limited results of lets say 50 people.

I also want to see if one person has hits in multiple different nodes with different labels and be able to sort them based on that and maybe on a ranking that says that a match in a Person node is higher ranked than a match in a Interest node.

I have tried different approaches, but find it hard to do all this in one query with 9 different labels. I also need the info about each person returned, which is the combination of all the different nodes (Person, Skills, Company etc).

This is what I have so far:

```
MATCH (person:Person)
WHERE person.name =~ '(?i).*some_search_query.*'
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT person) as persons 

UNION ALL 

MATCH(skill:Skill) <- [:HAS_SKILL] - (person:Person) 
WHERE skill.name =~ '(?i).*some_search_query.*'
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT person) as persons

UNION ALL
etc...
```

Is it better to approach this with several smaller cypher queries and then combine the results after they are returned?

How can I improve this query to include limits and sorting and also return all the info (Skills, Company, Interests etc) of every Person?

Is there a better approach in terms of performance?

I'm working with Node.js if that matters.

#### UPDATE:

I now have the following query:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (person:Person)
WHERE person.name =~ '(?i).*some_search_query.*'
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT person) as matchInPerson

OPTIONAL MATCH(skill:Skill) <- [:HAS_SKILL] - (person:Person)
WHERE skill.name =~ '(?i).*some_search_query.*'
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT person) as matchInSkill, matchInPerson

OPTIONAL MATCH(group:Skill) <- [:MEMBER_OF_GROUP] - (person:Person)
WHERE group.name =~ '(?i).*some_search_query.*'
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT person) as matchInGroups, matchInPerson, matchInSkill

OPTIONAL MATCH(company:Company) <- [rel:WORKED_AT] - (person:Person)
WHERE company.name =~ '(?i).*some_search_query.*' OR rel.description =~ '(?i).*some_search_query.*'
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT person) as matchInCompany, matchInPerson, matchInSkill, matchInGroups

OPTIONAL MATCH(country:Country) <- [:LIVES_IN] - (person:Person)
WHERE country.name =~ '(?i).*some_search_query.*'
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT person) as matchInCountry, matchInPerson, matchInSkill, matchInGroups, matchInCompany

OPTIONAL MATCH(city:City) <- [:LIVES_IN] - (person:Person)
WHERE city.name =~ '(?i).*some_search_query.*'
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT person) as matchInCity, matchInPerson, matchInSkill, matchInGroups, matchInCompany, matchInCountry

OPTIONAL MATCH(interest:Interest) <- [:HAS_INTEREST] - (person:Person)
WHERE interest.name =~ '(?i).*some_search_query.*'
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT person) as matchInInterest, matchInPerson, matchInSkill, matchInGroups, matchInCompany, matchInCountry, matchInCity

OPTIONAL MATCH(industry:Industry) <- [*1..2] - (person:Person)
WHERE industry.name =~ '(?i).*some_search_query.*'
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT person) as matchInIndustry, matchInPerson, matchInSkill, matchInGroups, matchInCompany, matchInCountry, matchInCity, matchInInterest

 OPTIONAL MATCH(certification:Certification) <- [rel:HAS_CERTIFICATION] - (person:Person)
WHERE certification.name =~ '(?i).*some_search_query.*' OR rel.by =~ '(?i).*some_search_query.*'
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT person) as matchInCertification, matchInPerson, matchInSkill, matchInGroups, matchInCompany, matchInCountry, matchInCity, matchInInterest, matchInIndustry

OPTIONAL MATCH(project:Project) <- [:WORKED_ON_PROJECT] - (person:Person)
WHERE project.name =~ '(?i).*some_search_query.*'
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT person) as matchInProject, matchInPerson, matchInSkill, matchInGroups, matchInCompany, matchInCountry, matchInCity, matchInInterest, matchInIndustry, matchInCertification

RETURN matchInPerson, matchInSkill, matchInGroups, matchInCompany, matchInCountry, matchInCity, matchInInterest, matchInIndustry, matchInCertification, matchInProject
```

this returns something like the following (results removed) :

```
[
   {
      "matchInPerson": [],
      "matchInSkill": [],
      "matchInGroups": [],
      "matchInCompany": [],
      "matchInCountry": [],
      "matchInCity": [],
      "matchInInterest": [],
      "matchInIndustry": [],
      "matchInCertification": [],
      "matchInProject": []
   }
]
```

matchInPerson and matchInSkills etc can now have duplicates, that is kind of intended, since I want to see if I can have matches in several nodes.

My problem now is that I need some way of removing the duplicates and then maybe add a property to the person that has duplicates, like person.matches += 1 for every duplicate (or some similar way to count how many mathces of one person I have).

And maybe most importantly I want to limit the response (after duplicates are removed and counted) since I don't wanna return thousands of results. Sorting the reults on number of duplicate hits would also be nice.

Hopefully this is achievable in the cypher query itself so that I don't have to process the results from the query.

Comment: Have you considered using [`WITH` statement](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-with.html#with-limit-branching-of-your-path-search)?

Comment: Yes, that is one of many approaches I have been trying.

Comment: Can you back up a step and explain more clearly what question or questions you are trying to ask of the system you are building? Ignoring neo4j for a moment and treating the system as a black box, what are your inputs and desired outputs?

Comment: Sure, my goal is to pass a parameter (string or strings) to the system and do a search in the database. I want to see how many hits I get on each person. Lets say I get 3 hits on person A (in skills, interests and groups), this person is now ranked higher in my search than person B which only has 2 hits etc.  

Now I want to sort the results from highest ranked to lowest, limit the result by i.e. 50 persons and then return the results.